# next-auth x Microsoft Graph API: Where to get the accessToken

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

I'm building an email marketing automation tool using NextJS, next-auth and Microsoft Graph API. I'm using next-auth's Azure AD B2C provider to authenticate users, and I've been following their [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad-b2c).

Within the **Configuration (Advanced)** section of the docs, I've followed the steps to setup an Azure AD api app to communicate with the Microsoft Graph API (to send email on our user's behalf). Now, when a user signs up, an `access_token` (jwt) is added to my `accounts` db table. Here it is decoded:

```
{
  "iss": "https://something.b2clogin.com/b03...f94/v2.0/",
  "exp": 1664588154,
  "nbf": 1664584554,
  "aud": "6eb...c5b",
  "idp_access_token": "EwB...QI=",
  "idp": "live.com",
  "name": "Will Despard",
  "sub": "1f7...d6c",
  "emails": [
    "willdespard@outlook.com"
  ],
  "tfp": "B2C_1_signupsignin",
  "scp": "mail.send",
  "azp": "ff8...f5d",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iat": 1664584554
}
```

The problem is, there is no example of how to setup the [Microsoft Graph JS Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) with next-auth. For example, according to Microsoft, to create a Microsoft Graph API client, you must do the following:

```
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';

const client = Client.init({
      authProvider: (done) =>
        done(
          null,
          accessToken // WHERE DO WE GET THIS FROM?
        ),
    });

const sendMail = {
      message: {
        subject: 'Meet for lunch?',
        body: { contentType: 'Text', content: 'The new cafeteria is open.' },
        toRecipients: [
          { emailAddress: { address: 'william.cm.despard@gmail.com' } },
        ],
      },
    };

const userDetails = await client.api('/me/sendMail').post(sendMail);
```

However, the following is unclear:

1. Where are we meant to get the accessToken used in this example from? I've tried using the `idp_access_token` in the decoded `accessToken` on my `accounts` db table (above), but this doesn't seem to work.
2. I'm assuming the accessToken we use to communicate with Microsoft Graph API is going to expire after a short amount of time. How do we handle getting a new token?

Help/code examples would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would try it like this. First, it looks that for graph access you should be looking for Azure AD provider, not Azure AD B2C that is a service that provides identity providers. I.e. looks like you need this one: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad

To use Microsoft Graph to send mail you'll also need to request a non-default scope with "Send Mail" grant from your user. Means, when authorizing your app the user will be asked to consent that your app will send emails on behalf of him. Also you'll need to save the graph access token you get from the authentication flow. Something like this:

```js
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad"

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    ....
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope:
            "openid email profile Mail.Send",
        },
      },
      // tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token
    },
```

Please note that if you do not specify tenantId that would mean that your application will be available for users from any tenant, but that in turn would mean that you must be a verified publisher (i.e. must have a valid [MPN ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/mpn-create-a-partner-center-account) associated with your app). If you do specify a tenantId, then your app will only work for users from that specified tenant.

Later on, you could just use the token from the API:

```js
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';

// some API function
export default async function handler(req, res) {

  const token = await getToken({ req })

  if (token) {

    const accessToken = token.accessToken;

    const client = Client.init({
      authProvider: (done) =>
        done(null, accessToken)
    });

    const sendMail = {
      message: {
        subject: 'Meet for lunch?',
        body: { contentType: 'Text', content: 'The new cafeteria is open.' },
        toRecipients: [
          { emailAddress: { address: 'william.cm.despard@gmail.com' } },
        ],
      },
    };
  
    const userDetails = await client.api('/me/sendMail').post(sendMail);
...
```

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for your answer. Regarding the first part, I think you CAN use Azure AD B2C for Graph access. For example, see the 'Configuration (Advanced)' section of the next-auth docs: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad-b2c Secondly, under the 'Example' section below 'Configuration (Advanced)', it shows how to add the scope correctly to the provider in authOptions. In contrast to your example, you need the full URL with the scope appended to the end. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The scopes work both ways (with url and without). Azure AD B2C is a service for authentication that Microsoft provides to the organizations (such as goverments for instance), so that they can implement authentication on their own. i.e. in this case of B2C you will authenticate not exactly against Microsoft, but against user custom authentication service that they have built on the base of Microsoft. I hope it clarifies the difference and the confusion. Here is more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview